# When trying to get ViewBinding working, why do some of my layout files need to start with <layout> while others don't?

Tags: android, android-layout

Basically after upgrading to Arctic Fox I've had to convert all my old style bindings to the new bindings.

For some layouts, the IDE will never generate the binding file on its own unless I wrap the entire layout on:

`<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">`

Yet other layouts work just fine without it. I haven't found any specific pattern, I have some that start with `LinearLayout` and that works just fine but yet another one that starts the same way required me to add `<layout>`.

Is there some requirement I'm missing? These are all within the same module.

Comment: FWIW, I have hundreds of layouts in a project, none of which have `<layout>`, and most of which are working with view binding (and a few that aren't using it yet). `<layout>` is for data binding. What do you have configured regarding data binding and view binding in your module's `build.gradle` file?

Comment: I have data binding enabled on a module I'm importing and that appears to be messing things up. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

It actually generated but sometimes the IDE won't show suggestions,
so what you need to do is type full name of the class then use your shortcuts to import it

example: your layout name is *activity_main.xml*
then just type *ActivityMainBinding*

don't wait for IDE suggestion

if you want to show IDE suggestion then clean the project and rebuild, it will generate the files for you

or check is there anything you miss:
[View Binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding)

Comment: Thank for the suggestion but the issue was what @CommonsWare suggested. I had data binding on a module.